# How do I unbind `<prefix> space` in tmux?

Tags: layout, tmux, prefix

`<prefix> space` by default switches to the next layout. I never want to do this, as I like to keep it default but sometimes I accidentally trigger it.

In my tmux conf I have:

```
# unbind prefix-space to rearrage windows
unbind C-Space
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`next-layout` binding is bound to `Space` not `C-Space` so you basically need to

```
unbind Space
```

Don't forget to source your `tmux.conf` after this

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```